# Debugging options in Julia

Tags: debugging, gdb, julia

I am using Juno package in an atom ide to debug the Julia code. How can I step into the function? The function is imported from a different file. I can execute a set of lines by selecting them and then pressing "ctrl+enter". Is there any short-cut for stepping into a function and execute line by line in the function. Thank you. 
Is it possible to debug Julia code using gdb? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Historically there was `Gallium.jl` and it integrated nicely with Julia 0.6. 
The full-blown debugger is still work-in-progress in Julia.

Now this is the best you can do.

#### What works:

the best bet today is probably to try `Debugger.jl`. Press `]` for the package manager

```
add https://github.com/JuliaDebug/JuliaInterpreter.jl
add https://github.com/JuliaDebug/Debugger.jl
```

Once installed after `using Debugger` you can use `@enter` macro to control function flow.

Another option to try out is [Rebugger.jl](https://github.com/timholy/Rebugger.jl)

#### The future:

There are two nice thread on Julia discourse explaining the current state:

- [Compiler work priorities](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/compiler-work-priorities/17623)
- [State of the debugger](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/state-of-the-debugger/4308/23)